# Не отрабатывают медиа запросы

Tags: css3, адаптивная-верстка, sass

**SASS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 990px)
    body
        .siteWrapper    
            #menuAccordion
                margin-left: 10%

            .content
                .wrapper
                    .item
                        width: 50%

@media screen and (max-width: 400px)
    body
        .siteWrapper
            .content
                .wrapper
                    .item
                        width: 100%!important
```

Отрабатывает только первый медиа запрос, второй `max-width: 400px` не работает.

Как быть?

Comment: проверьте для начала отладчик (кнопка F12 в браузере) - надо определиться для начала, не работают ваши стили в браузере, или просто перебиваются другими из-за, например, недостаточного веса селекторов

Comment: браузер в отладчике вообще не видит медиа запрос max-width: 400. Для ширины экрана в 320px показывает, что работает медиа запрос max-width: 990px

Comment: в редакторе http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWwmox?editors=1100 ваш код работает. ищите ошибки где-то у себя

Comment: Проверил, как раз отрабатывает только один медиа запрос для 990px, а тот который делает блок шириной 100% не работает

Comment: После добавления тега <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> запросы заработали